# Delete Custom module

Tags: magento2, module, delete, uninstall-module

I am new to magento development, made a custom module
Vendor: Scandiweb
Module: Scandiweb_Test
The naming convention is not correct so I decided to delete it, I can't run module:uninstall because its not installed from composer, I deleted the directory and the occurance in app/etc/config also checked db setup_modules, the module name is not present.

Now whatever I do I am getting this error:
How do I solve this?

```
PHP Warning: require_once(/app/code/Scandiweb/Scandiweb_Test/registration.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php on line 29
```

Comment: After deleting the folder. Did you ran setup upgrade command?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your config.php file in the following path

`app/etc/config.php`

Find your module name there. If it is present then change the value from "1" to "0" and run the following command,

`bin/magento setup:upgrade`

If it is not present then run the above upgrade command and check if the error is still there.

Comment: Already tried this before, still getting same error

Comment: Try making the module with the name provided in your error and make a registration.php file for it. Then run the upgrade command. This might fix your issue!

Comment: I know it will fix the error but I wish to delete the module :)

Comment: Run these commands. This will delete any previous files and make new ones.

bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
bin/magento c:f
bin/magento indexer:reindex
bin/magento c:f

Comment: It got solved for now, I shared in an answer, But I'll try your shared commands if I face this again. Thanks

Comment: No problem. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I cleared the cache from docker terminal and run setup:upgrade, and it worked after that.